Unable to remount root partition: "Operation not permitted"
I have a device, rooted through the KernelSU. I granted root access to the Termux app using the KernelSU app. Now I have access to the su command, and theoretically should be able to use the mount command within the su shell. But when I try to use it for my root partition /, it says:
mount: '/dev/block/dm-2'->'/': Operation not permitted
What I want is to mount the root as read-write, but any mount operation I've tried failed.
The commands I've tried:
mount -o rw,remount /
mount -o ro,remount /
Or maybe there's another way to make the root writable?

To my knowledge this is quite normal. On modern devices you can't remount root partition - even with root permissions. That is the reason why Magisk uses file-system overlays to simulate modifications.
